# Google map API как получить общее время в пути

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Подскажите кто сталкивался уже с таким. Работаю на сайте с картами Google, подключены API: Maps JavaScript API, Places API, Directions API.

Маршруты строятся нормально, всё работает, но не получается получить общее время в пути. Или просто время от каждой точки к точке.
Документацию смотрел, и что то ничего не нашёл там.
Может кто делал, подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

В ответе от Directions API возвращается массив `routes[]`, он содержит объекты `DirectionsRoute` (объекты маршрутов), в каждом объекте имеется массив `legs[]`, который содержит объекты `DirectionsLeg` (этапы маршрута - от точки до точки). В этом объекте есть много интересного, например, то что Вам нужно: distance (расстояние) и duration (время), оба имеют text (текстовое представление значения) и value (значение, цифра - время в секундах, расстояние в метрах). Или, например, `start_address` и `end_address`.

Суммированием значений по каждому Leg выбранного Вами маршрута, можете получить общее время в пути.

[Документация по Directions Routes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Routes)